# Attribute level authorization in views with pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

I'm using pundit for authorization in a rails app. For some models, I want attribute-level authorization. For example, a normal user is allowed to change his phone number but can't set his status to "administrator".

As recommended in [the Pundit docs](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#strong-parameters), I'm using the `permitted_attributes` for this.

I now want to access these attributes in a view to decide which fields to show or enable in a form. Is there an (elegant) way to do this without essentially repeating the authorized fields there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you may want to add some nice shortcuts in your `ApplicationPolicy` which lets you check if attributes are permitted:

```
class ApplicationPolicy 
  #...

  def permits_attributes?(*attrs)
    attrs.keep_if({|a| permits_attribute?(a) }).any?
  end

  def permits_attribute?(attr)
    permitted_attributes.include?(attr)
  end

  # ...
end
```

You could then create a custom form builder (or a module that extends a form builder):

```
class MyFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def can_fill_in?(attr)
    yield if @template.policy(object).permits_attribute?(attr)
  end
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@project, builder: MyFormBuilder) do |f| %>
  <%= f.can_fill_in?(:title) do %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can also configure rails to use your custom form builder by default:

```
ActionView::Base.default_form_builder = MyFormBuilder
```

See:

- [ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html)

Comment: Thanks, I added the methods to application policy and created the custom form builder, but I can't seem to access the policy from the helper. I get an "undefined method `policy' for #<MyFormBuilder:0x007fcd123cccd8>"

Comment: did you try calling @template.policy? I shaw that i made a typo and wrote it with a space. @template is a link to the view context which should have the policy - not the form builder class.

Comment: Yes, I tried both @template.policy and view_context.policy. In the view itself, I can access policy without problem.

Comment: Nevermind, @template.policy works fine. Because the default_form_builder is set in an initializer, I had to restart rails server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: There's another small issue with the suggested code. `permitted_attributes.include?(attrs)` doesn't work since attrs is array. This should be something like `attrs.all? { |e| permitted_attributes.include?(e) }`

Comment: This seems to be working however, when the attribute is permitted the field is rendered twice.